# Drupal Editing Tools missing

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-5

Went into my site and the site would not load. I had my friend look at the site and here is what he told me.

"I had to upload Drupal core files for version 5 and reconnect everything. 
The previous user id’s and passwords should all work, there may be some missing data as I did have to pull one of the database files from back up so the site will have to be checked for integrity/links etc."

After he did that, the page was back up and running but editing tools were missing. In the edit mode, the page only shows html and no visual editing.

I also have not been able to access a page containing a calendar that was there before as a link from the home page.

Here is the URL - www.kntram.com.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you ask your friend for help on this?

Comment: You should contact Drupal support.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) (or similar editors like FCKEditor and TinyMCE) modules have probably just been deactivated when your friend replaced data in the database.

If you can, go to the `Admin -> Site Building -> Modules` page and reactivate the module (if it's missing, follow the link to download it, and upload it to the "modules" folder of your website).

If it's already activated, check the roles permissions in `Admin -> User Managagement -> Permissions` because the role your user belong to simply may not have the permission to use the editor activated.